# Dice rolls into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dice

I am wondering why i get the message: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: d1 is not defined' at the console

I want to add the dice rolls into an array.

this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
  var diceRolls = [];
  diceRolls.push(d1);

  if (diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 1] === d1) {
      console.log("Je hebt 5 punten gewonnen!");
  }     

function rollDice() {
           var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
           var status = document.getElementById("status");               
           var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
           console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");


  }



  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>

    <button onclick="rollDice()"> Roll the dice </button>
    <h2 id="status" style="clear:left":> </h2>
</body>
```

Comment: ...because you never defined `d1` perhaps?

Comment: You're defining D1 after you use it for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The second line of the script is trying to push `d1` into `diceRolls` when you haven't initialized `d1` yet. You'd have to declare `rollDice()` above the rest of the script, and then call it to push a value into `diceRolls`.

I think you might want to try something along these lines?

```
var diceRolls = [];

function rollDice() {
  var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
  var status = document.getElementById("status");               
  var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
  console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");
  diceRolls.push(d1);
}

if (diceRolls[diceRolls.length - 1] === d1) {
    console.log("Je hebt 5 punten gewonnen!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diceRolls.push(d1);
```

At the point the browser reaches this line, d1 hasn't been set yet. I think if you throw that into the rollDice function you will get what you're after. In other words:

```
function rollDice() {
       var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
       var status = document.getElementById("status");               
       var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
       console.log("You rolled "+d1+".");
       diceRolls.push(d1);
 }
```

Edit: AVP beat me by about 30 seconds, he gets my vote.